# Airflow plugin model views Not Secured

Tags: airflow

How to protect Airflow custom **model** views added via Plugin system from unauthenticated user ? I'm currently using password protection but pages added by my plugin can be accessed without being logged in...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same `@login_required` decorator that the protected [builtin views](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2/airflow/www/views.py#L298) use.

```
import airflow

login_required = airflow.login.login_required

class TestView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    @login_required
    def test(self):
        ...
```

Comment: It seems clear, but I'm using `ModelView` extended class which does not define a method with `@expose(...)`. Where setting up `@login_required` stuff?

Comment: To extend that answer: In version 1.9, this won't work (at least for me). Try using the required_login-Decorator from the flask_login Package directly: `from flask_login import login_required`

Comment: Did you find any answer, I am facing the same problem?